# How to check if input string matches a specific format?

Tags: bash, shell-script

The user can write in my Bash script a mac address in the following way:

```
read -p "enter mac-address " mac-address
```

Now i want to check in an if-statement, if this mac-address matches with a "specific" format. i.e. it should be `FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF` and not `FFFFFFFFFFFF`. Also the length should be correct: 6x2.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The lazy way is just to run

```
if [[ $mac_address == ??:??:??:??:??:?? ]]; then echo Heureka; fi
```

but this doesn't check whether it's a hex string. So if this is important

```
if [[ $mac_address =~ ^[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]:[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]:[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]:[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]:[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]:[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]$ ]]; then echo Heureka; fi
```

might be better. The later can be shortened to

```
if [[ $mac_address =~ ^([[:xdigit:]]{2}:){5}[[:xdigit:]]{2}$ ]]; then
    echo Heureka; 
fi
```

If the pattern matches I don't see a need to check for the correct length as well.

Comment: Note that `[a-f]` also matches on `â`, `é` (and many other characters) with `bash` and in most of today's locales. Better to use `[[:xdigit:]]` as you do for the last example, or `[0-9abcdefABCDEF]`

Answer (score 6):

```
[[ $mac_address: =~ ^([[:xdigit:]]{2}:){6}$ ]]
```

Comment: That's almost too clever, the only thing that makes it work is somewhat easy to miss. I think you'd still need to anchor the start of the string.

Comment: I would vote this up multiple times if I could. I didn't understand how it could work, didn't catch the trick until I pasted into an xterm to test, and started to replace `$mac_address` with a literal, then I saw it.

Answer (score 5):

I changed the name of the variable so that it consisted of legal characters, then used the `=~` test operator to compare the value to the extended regular expression matching: at the beginning of the string `^`, "2 hex digits and a colon" 5 times, followed by 2 hex digits, ending the string `$`:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "enter mac-address " mac_address

if [[ $mac_address =~ ^([[:xdigit:]][[:xdigit:]]:){5}[[:xdigit:]][[:xdigit:]]$ ]]
then
  echo good
else
  echo bad
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

With standard `sh` syntax (so would work with `bash` and any other POSIX compatible shell):

```
x='[[:xdigit:]]'
mac_pattern="$x$x:$x$x:$x$x:$x$x:$x$x:$x$x"

printf >&2 'Please enter a MAC address: '; read mac
case $mac in
  ($mac_pattern) echo OK;;
  (*) echo >&2 BAD;;
esac
```